# explanation about push ebp and pop ebp instruction in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, callstack, stack-frame

i used stack in assembly but i didn't got idea about push ebp  and pop ebp.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.include "console.i"

.text

askl:   .asciz  "Enter length: "
askb:   .asciz  "Enter breadth: "
ans:    .asciz  "Perimeter = "

_entry:

    push    ebp     # establishing stack-frame
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 12

    Prompt  askl
    GetInt  [ebp-4]     # length
    Prompt  askb
    GetInt  [ebp-8]     # breadth

    mov eax, [ebp-4]    # eax = l
    add eax, [ebp-8]    # eax = l + b
    add eax, eax    # eax = 2 * (l + b)
    mov [ebp-12], eax

    Prompt  ans
    PutInt  [ebp-12]
    PutEoL

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp     # unwinding stack-frame
    ret

.global _entry

.end
```

Comment: It's always best to give more context than less. That said, the actual question is really vague and would use some more explanation.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Maybe you're wondering about this:

```
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 12
```

These lines are known as the assembly function prologue.  The first 2 instructions save the previous base pointer (ebp) and set EBP to point at that position on the stack (right below the return address).  This sets up EBP as a [*frame pointer*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/303446/why-is-a-frame-pointer-set-as-an-offset-from-the-stack-pointer).

The `sub esp,12` line is saving space for local variables in the function.  That space can be addressed with addressing modes like `[ebp - 4]`.  Any push/pop of function args, or the `call` instruction itself pushing a return address, or stack frames for functions we call, will happen below this reserved space, at the current ESP.

At the end you have:

```
mov esp, ebp         ; restore ESP
pop ebp              ; restore caller's EBP
ret                  ; pop the return address into EIP
```

This is the inverse the prologue does (i.e. the epilogue), so the previous context can be restored.  This is sometimes called "tearing down" the stack frame.

(EBP is non-volatile aka call-preserved in all standard x86 calling conventions: if you modify it, you have to restore your caller's value.)

The [`leave`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/leave) instruction does exactly what these two instructions do, and is used by some compilers to save code size.  (`enter 0,0` is very slow and never used (https://agner.org/optimize/); `leave` is about as efficient as mov + pop.)

---

Note that using EBP as a frame pointer is *optional*, and compilers don't do it for most functions in optimized code.  Instead they save separate metadata to allow stack unwinding / backtrace.

Comment: Also note that you have an instruction called `leave` which is exactly what `mov esp, ebp` and 
`pop ebp` does.

Answer (score 53):

`ebp` is known as the base pointer or the frame pointer.  On entry to your function, you push it (to save the value for the calling function).  Then, you copy `esp`, the stack pointer, into `ebp`, so that `ebp` now points to your function's stack frame.  At the end of your function, you then pop `ebp` so that the calling function's value is restored.

For some clarification on exactly what is going on - the `push` instruction puts the value from the specified register (`ebp` in this case), onto the stack, and decrements the stack pointer by the appropriate amount.  The `pop` operation is the opposite - it increments the stack pointer and takes a value from the stack and puts it in the specified register.

Comment: I have a question about this. 

Does "push ebp" push the "value" of ebp and then "mov ebp, esp" update the ebp's address?